# JdbcTemplate. IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException: Incorrect column count

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I use Spring JdbcTemplate to query list of several values:

```
List<String[]> tankNames = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
                "select name, country, level from tanklist", String[].class);
```

get the following error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.IncorrectResultSetColumnCountException:
>   Incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 3

1. Why it expects 1 as I use *String[]*?
2. How I can get a list of values of several columns (maybe in an array of Strings) without creating an object of these 3 values?

My final goal to transform this response to a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following method instead to simplify your implementation

```
<T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)
```

If you want to get list of String array (String[]) i.e. columns of each row are elements of a String array, use following

```
List<String[]> allTankNames = jdbcTemplate.query(
    "select name, country, level from tanklist", 
    (rs, rowNum) -> new String[] {rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)});
```

However, your code suggests you want to get one string per row having concatenated all columns, for that, use following

```
List<String> allTankNames = jdbcTemplate.query(
    "select name, country, level from tanklist", 
    (rs, rowNum) -> String.format("%s %s %s", rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> allTankNames = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
                "select name, country, level from tanklist");
```

My goal was to transform this into a list of strings:

```
List<String> tankNamesWithInfo = allTankNames.stream().map(m -> (String) m.get("name") + m.get("country") + m.get("level")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```